# Abnormaly fast animation speed with Andengine

Tags: android, animation, andengine

I am using Andengine to build my game on Android and I use an AnimatedSprite to draw a running ninja. I am using the method changeFrameDuration to modify the animation speed depending on the speed that the ninja is moving.

I don't know why the animation is sometime very fast when it should be slow according to the frame duration value that I set.

I printed logs to see why my ninja was animated very fast and the current tile index is telling some interesting things...

```
** Here the ninja is animated very slowly like supposed **
06-17 23:03:08.868: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 1639 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.888: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2048 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.908: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.928: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.948: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.968: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:08.988: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.008: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.028: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.048: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.068: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.088: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.108: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.129: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.149: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.169: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.189: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.209: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 2561 with current tile index : 0

** Here it starts behing animated very fast (when supposed to be not very fast) **
06-17 23:03:09.229: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 741 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.249: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 521 with current tile index : 2
06-17 23:03:09.269: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 421 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.289: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 361 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.309: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 320 with current tile index : 4
06-17 23:03:09.329: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 290 with current tile index : 5
06-17 23:03:09.349: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 266 with current tile index : 5
06-17 23:03:09.369: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 248 with current tile index : 6
06-17 23:03:09.389: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 232 with current tile index : 7
06-17 23:03:09.409: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 220 with current tile index : 7
06-17 23:03:09.429: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 208 with current tile index : 8
06-17 23:03:09.449: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 199 with current tile index : 8
06-17 23:03:09.469: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 190 with current tile index : 9
06-17 23:03:09.489: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 183 with current tile index : 9
06-17 23:03:09.509: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 176 with current tile index : 10
06-17 23:03:09.529: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 170 with current tile index : 10
06-17 23:03:09.549: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 165 with current tile index : 11
06-17 23:03:09.569: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 160 with current tile index : 11

** Here it starts behing animated at a normal rate (slowly accelerating) **
06-17 23:03:09.589: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 155 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.609: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 151 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.629: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 147 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.649: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 143 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.669: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 140 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.689: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 137 with current tile index : 0
06-17 23:03:09.709: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 134 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.729: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 131 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.749: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 128 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.769: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 126 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.789: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 124 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.809: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 121 with current tile index : 1
06-17 23:03:09.829: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 119 with current tile index : 2
06-17 23:03:09.849: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 117 with current tile index : 2
06-17 23:03:09.869: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 115 with current tile index : 2
06-17 23:03:09.889: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 113 with current tile index : 2
06-17 23:03:09.909: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 112 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.929: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 110 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.949: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 108 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.969: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 107 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:09.989: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 105 with current tile index : 3
06-17 23:03:10.009: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 104 with current tile index : 4
06-17 23:03:10.029: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 103 with current tile index : 4
06-17 23:03:10.049: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 101 with current tile index : 4
06-17 23:03:10.070: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 100 with current tile index : 4
06-17 23:03:10.090: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 99 with current tile index : 5
06-17 23:03:10.110: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 98 with current tile index : 5
06-17 23:03:10.130: I/Ninja(15495): Animation frame duration : 97 with current tile index : 5
```

And now about my code, here are the important parts.

First, I have a GameScene that extends BaseScene.

```
public class GameScene extends BaseScene {
private static final String TAG = "GameScene";
private static final int TIME_BETWEEN_EACH_POSITION_BROADCAST = 250;

private AutoParallaxBackground parallaxBackground;
private Ninja player;
private Vector<Ninja> ninjas;
public int time;
public boolean isStarted = false;
private int timeSinceLastPositionBroadcast = 0;

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    if(isStarted){
        int timeElapsed = Math.round(pSecondsElapsed*1000);
        Log.d(TAG, "Last time: "+time+", time elapsed: "+timeElapsed+", current time: "+(time+timeElapsed));
        time += timeElapsed;
        for(Ninja ninja : ninjas){
            ninja.update(pSecondsElapsed);
        }
        centerScreenOnPlayer();
        parallaxBackground.setParallaxChangePerSecond(player.getSpeed()/120f);
        timeSinceLastPositionBroadcast += timeElapsed;
        if(timeSinceLastPositionBroadcast >= TIME_BETWEEN_EACH_POSITION_BROADCAST){
            timeSinceLastPositionBroadcast -= TIME_BETWEEN_EACH_POSITION_BROADCAST;
            MessageManager.getInstance().broadcastPosition(time, player.getX(), player.getY());
        }
    }
}

private void centerScreenOnPlayer(){
    float newCenterX = player.getX()+200;
    float newCenterY = player.getY()+25;
    camera.setCenter(newCenterX, newCenterY);
}
}
```

And then I have the Ninja class that extends AnimatedSprite.

```
public class Ninja extends AnimatedSprite {

    public void update(float secondsElapsed){
        updateX(secondsElapsed);
        updateY();
        updateAnimationSpeed();
        float maxSpeedParticleEmitterX = this.getX() + this.getWidth()/4;
        float maxSpeedParticleEmitterY = this.getY() + this.getHeight()/4;
        if(this.getWidth() != this.getWidthScaled()){
            maxSpeedParticleEmitterX -= this.getWidth()/4 * scaleModificationPercentage;
            maxSpeedParticleEmitterY -= this.getHeight()/4 * scaleModificationPercentage;
        }
        maxSpeedParticleEmitter.setCenter(maxSpeedParticleEmitterX, maxSpeedParticleEmitterY);
        maxSpeedParticleSystem.setCurrentTileIndex(this.getCurrentTileIndex());
        slice.setX(this.getX()+this.getWidth());
        slice.setY(this.getY());
    }

    private void updateAnimationSpeed(){
        float divideBy = currentSpeed;
        if(divideBy < 10)
            divideBy = 10;
        int frameDuration = (int) (ANIMATION_SPEED * MAX_MOVEMENT_SPEED / divideBy);    //y = k / x ... where k = 50 * 600 ... (normal max animation speed * max speed)
        if(this.isPlayer)
            Log.i(TAG, "Animation frame duration : "+frameDuration+" with current tile index : "+this.getCurrentTileIndex());
        this.changeFrameDuration(frameDuration);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of why my animated sprite is changing rapidly its tile index while it's supposed to change it slowly?

Comment: Post your code that sets the speed. There's nothing to see in the log except that it does in fact do what you say.

Comment: I added the important parts of my code concerning my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the AnimatedSprite is not meant to have its frame duration changed so drastically on the fly (from > 2000 to < 1000). I don't know why it changes frames faster than supposed but I managed to solve my problem by stopping the animation when the frame duration is over 500 and starting it back when it is under 500.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is use ANIMATION_SPEED * (currentSpeed/MAX_MOVEMENTSPEED) - the parentheses are important. you want to have a percent (current/maximum) times a constant (AnimationSpeed)

```
int animationSpeed = (int) (ANIMATION_SPEED * (currentSpeed / MAX_MOVEMENT_SPEED));
```

Comment: To add to that, this article here says that `*` takes precedence over `\\` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Actualy, what I want to have is the opposite. My variable name is not very good, it should be named frameDuration... So it is ok to divide the max over the current, so when the ninja goes fast, the frameDuration is short. And the parentheses aren't important at all, it is just a multiplication and a division, there is no need of priority. This is basic maths...